# Python Recursive File System Search Function

Tags: python, recursion, filesystems

I'm new to this site and relatively new to Python.  I'm currently working on a project that requires me to write a recursive search function to look through files and directories.  The function takes a directory path, and search criteria, in this case, a file name, and is supposed to return the full path to the file, provided it exists.

```
def search(path, file):
fullPath = path
inDir = os.listdir(path)

for element in inDir:
    if os.path.join(path, file) == os.path.join(path, element):
        fullPath = os.path.join(fullPath, file)
        print(fullPath)
        return fullPath
    elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, element)):
        fullPath = search(os.path.join(path, element), file)
```

I know that recursion in Python requires a return statement on the recursive call, but I've also tried:

```
def search(path, file):
fullPath = path
inDir = os.listdir(path)

for element in inDir:
    if os.path.join(path, file) == os.path.join(path, element):
        fullPath = os.path.join(fullPath, file)
        print(fullPath)
        return fullPath
    elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, element)):
        return search(os.path.join(path, element), file)
```

and several other variations, but to no avail.  The first function prints the correct path, so I know that at some point in the recursion `fullPath` contains correct path, but I can't seem to get the function to return anything except `None`.

Comment: Er, why are you not just using `os.walk` for this?

Comment: I realize that os.walk could be used for this, but I'm restricted from using it.  I'm essentially try to build a program that replicates os.walk.

Comment: @user2848412: You might want to look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/os.py#l337) for `os.walk`, which is pretty simple, and might inspire you in writing your similar function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
for element in inDir:
    if os.path.join(path, file) == os.path.join(path, element):
        fullPath = os.path.join(fullPath, file)
        print(fullPath)
        return fullPath
    elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, element)):
        return search(os.path.join(path, element), file)
```

It goes through the files one by one. The first time you find a matching file, you return  it—which is good.

But the first time you find any directory, you just search that directory and return the result—which is bad.

If you get through a whole directory without finding a match or a subdirectory, you fall off the end of the function, which means you return `None`.

So, imagine this structure:

```
root/
    sub1/
        sub1a/
            notthefile
    sub2/
        thefile
```

You start off looking through `root`. Because `sub1` is a directory, you return the result of searching `sub1`. Because `sub1a` is a directory, you return the result of searching `sub1a`. Because `sub1a` doesn't have any directories, or any matching files, you return `None`.

---

So, how can you fix this? Simple: If a recursive search fails, don't just return its value, keep going through the loop:

```
elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, element)):
    fullpath = search(os.path.join(path, element), file)
    if fullpath is not None:
        return fullpath
```

---

You've also got a minor problem once you fix this. If you get to the right directory, then find any subdirectories before you find the file, you will have reassigned `fullPath` to `None`, so that `os.path.join(fullPath, file)` will fail. You want to use the original value, from the start of the function, no matter what.

Fortunately, you already have that original version, in `path`. And, once you use that, you don't need `fullPath` for anything, so you might as well just scrap it.

Comment: After hours of beating my head a against a wall I get an incredibly informed response in three minutes.  Thank you so much.  I see that I accounted for two of three possibilities of the search: finding the file, and finding more directories; but not _not_ finding the file... or anything!  I'll remember next time.

Comment: @austinsherron: You'll never remember _everything_. Or at least _I_ never remember everything… It's much easier to create a small data set (in this case, three directories and two files) and actually step through your code in the debugger (or print out the intermediate paths, or something equivalent) to figure what you forgot, than to try to remember what you forgot (especially since, if you can remember it, you wouldn't have forgotten).

Answer (score 2):

Why not os.walk() http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk probably does most of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For something completely different,  but not as extensible. Try glob

```
from glob import glob
print glob("**/filename")
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Extended globs aren't well documented for python2 but it appears to work on my system.